# Use another workbook when macro is on current workbook

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to code a macro that will add some columns of the current workbook consulting other workbook. I am kind of new to excel Vba and i tried to find answers in the internet before asking here.  Thanks in advance

My code:

```
Sub Mono_recurso()
'
' Mono_recurso Macro
'
lin_ori = 2
lin_dest = 2


Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet

Set wkb = Excel.Workbooks("C:\Users\Feels Bad Man\Desktop\exemplo.xlsm")
Set wks = wkb.Worksheets("Tabela de síntese")


Do While Sheets("Mono").Cells(lin_ori, 1) <> ""


Sheets("Mono recurso").Cells(lin_dest, 1) = Sheets("Mono").Cells(lin_ori, 1)
Sheets("Mono recurso").Cells(lin_dest, 2) = Sheets("Mono").Cells(lin_ori, 2)

lin_ori = lin_ori + 1
lin_dest = lin_dest + 1

Loop



lin_ori = 3
lin_dest = 2


Do While Sheets("Mono recurso").Cells(lin_dest, 1) <> ""

Do While wkb.wks.Cells(lin_ori, 2) ' <> ""))


If Sheets("Mono recurso").Cells(lin_dest, 1) = wkb.wks.Cells(lin_ori, 2) Then


    Sheets("Mono recurso").Cells(lin_dest, 3) = wkb.wks.Cells(lin_ori, 6)
    Sheets("Mono recurso").Cells(lin_dest, 4) = wkb.wks.Cells(lin_ori, 7)
    Sheets("Mono recurso").Cells(lin_dest, 5) = wkb.wks.Cells(lin_ori, 8)
    Sheets("Mono recurso").Cells(lin_dest, 6) = wkb.wks.Cells(lin_ori, 15)
    Sheets("Mono recurso").Cells(lin_dest, 7) = wkb.wks.Cells(lin_ori, 16)

    lin_ori = lin_ori + 1

Else

    lin_ori = lin_ori + 1

End If

Loop

lin_dest = lin_dest + 1



Loop

'
End Sub
```

I tried several solutions but my code just run till it reaches this:

```
Set wkb = Excel.Workbooks("C:\Users\Feels Bad Man\Desktop\exemplo.xlsm")
```

Comment: That line should just say `Set wkb = Excel.Workbooks("exemplo.xlsm")`.  Because Excel won't permit two workbooks to be open with the same filename, it will know that the one you are referring to is the one you opened from `C:\Users\Feels Bad Man\Desktop`.

Comment: Alright, i tried that but it still stops in the same line... Is it possible to use both workbooks? i mean the one where i am working and the other i want to load to perform the cycles. So i dont have to merge both of excel files into one

Comment: Always provide the error number and exact message in questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption is that you want to open the other workbook from your code, transfer some of its values into the workbook containing your macro, and then probably close the other workbook.

There were a couple issues with your code, which I've tried to address below. The comments provide some details.

```
'Always put Option Explicit at the top of your modules.
'Declare all variables and compile your code (menu: Debug / Compile).
Option Explicit

'
' Mono_recurso Macro
'
Sub Mono_recurso()
    Dim exemploWbk As Excel.Workbook
    Dim tabelaSinteseWks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim monoWks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim monoRecursoWks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lin_ori As Long
    Dim lin_dest As Long

    'Open the workbook.
    'Note: there are many options to the Open method; check them online.
    Set exemploWbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Feels Bad Man\Desktop\exemplo.xlsm")

    'Obtain a reference to the target worksheet.
    Set tabelaSinteseWks = exemploWbk.Worksheets("Tabela de síntese")

    'Obtain references to local worksheets.
    'Notice the use of ThisWorkbook; without it, Excel would try to find worksheet "Mono" in the Active workbook,
    'which might not be the one you'd expect.
    Set monoWks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Mono")
    Set monoRecursoWks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Mono recurso")

    'Haven't tried to understand what you want to do, but notice the use of the references obtained above,
    'the Value2 property for good practice (without it, you're dealing with Range objects and relying on
    'VBA to use the default property of the Range class), and the correction from your original "wkb.wks"
    'to just "...Wks".

    lin_ori = 2
    lin_dest = 2
    Do While monoWks.Cells(lin_ori, 1).Value2 <> ""
        monoRecursoWks.Cells(lin_dest, 1).Value2 = monoWks.Cells(lin_ori, 1).Value2
        monoRecursoWks.Cells(lin_dest, 2).Value2 = monoWks.Cells(lin_ori, 2).Value2

        lin_ori = lin_ori + 1
        lin_dest = lin_dest + 1
    Loop

    lin_ori = 3
    lin_dest = 2
    Do While monoRecursoWks.Cells(lin_dest, 1).Value2 <> ""
        Do While tabelaSinteseWks.Cells(lin_ori, 2).Value2 <> "" 'Note: you had commented out this comparison.
            If monoRecursoWks.Cells(lin_dest, 1) = tabelaSinteseWks.Cells(lin_ori, 2) Then
                monoRecursoWks.Cells(lin_dest, 3) = tabelaSinteseWks.Cells(lin_ori, 6)
                monoRecursoWks.Cells(lin_dest, 4) = tabelaSinteseWks.Cells(lin_ori, 7)
                monoRecursoWks.Cells(lin_dest, 5) = tabelaSinteseWks.Cells(lin_ori, 8)
                monoRecursoWks.Cells(lin_dest, 6) = tabelaSinteseWks.Cells(lin_ori, 15)
                monoRecursoWks.Cells(lin_dest, 7) = tabelaSinteseWks.Cells(lin_ori, 16)
            End If

            lin_ori = lin_ori + 1
        Loop

        lin_dest = lin_dest + 1
    Loop

    'Release references to objects within the other workbook before closing it.
    Set tabelaSinteseWks = Nothing
    exemploWbk.Close SaveChanges:=False

    'Cleanup.
    Set monoRecursoWks = Nothing
    Set monoWks = Nothing
    Set exemploWbk = Nothing
End Sub
```

There's a cool thing you can do with worksheets in the workbook containing your macro: use their **CodeName** directly in VBA. A worksheet's CodeName can be seen and modified from the Visual Basic Editor. The cool part is that this name will not change even if you change the worksheet's name from Excel.

In the Project Explorer (Ctrl+R), select a worksheet (say, `Mono`) under the `Microsoft Excel Objects` node, and press F4 to go to its Properties window. Change the `(Name)` property. Right now it's probably `Sheet1` or something. Change it to `monoWks`. Do the same for the `Mono recurso` worksheet, naming it `monoRecursoWks`.

Once this is done, you can get rid of several lines of code, because you can refer to those two local worksheets by their CodeName directly. The bonus, again, is that you don't have to worry about your code breaking should their names, as seen from Excel, change.

```
Sub Mono_recurso()
    Dim exemploWbk As Excel.Workbook
    Dim tabelaSinteseWks As Excel.Worksheet
    '... No need to declare variables to hold local worksheet references ...
    Dim lin_ori As Long
    Dim lin_dest As Long

    'Open the workbook.
    'Note: there are many options to the Open method; check them online.
    Set exemploWbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Feels Bad Man\Desktop\exemplo.xlsm")

    '... No need to get references to local worksheets by their tab names in Excel ...

    'Obtain a reference to the target worksheet.
    Set tabelaSinteseWks = exemploWbk.Worksheets("Tabela de síntese")

    '... Copy code goes here, unchanged ...

    'Release references to objects within the other workbook before closing it.
    Set tabelaSinteseWks = Nothing
    exemploWbk.Close SaveChanges:=False

    'Cleanup.
    Set exemploWbk = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow it is running now but it is not doing what i want it to do... You used "value2" does this work if my Cells have a String?
What i am trying to do is to find out if there's the same string that i have in the Spreadsheet (Mono) in the Example.xmlx in the spreadsheet (Tabela de Síntese) if it does it will copy some data of the columns of that sheet to my original one. I want it to work this way so i dont have an excel file with 25Mb.
I am glad that you came up with this solution and this code. All i know about excel-vba was learned by me in the last month so i don't know to code properly yet

Comment: Yes, Value2 will work with anything that's stored in a cell.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working fine. I learnt a lot with this code example :)